# Poco HTTPRequestHandler handleRequest aborting after multiple requests

Tags: poco-libraries

I based my server off the HTTPTimeServer.  The minute I try to log in the handleRequest I can't send the server multiple requests.  The second one aborts the server.  I thought it was a multi-threading issue hence the mutex scope but that didn't make a difference.

This seems to be a common pattern with the Poco HTTPTimeServer and an easy pitfall.  What am I missing here?

```
std::mutex g_log_mutex;

void WifiRequestHandler::handleRequest(HTTPServerRequest& request, HTTPServerResponse& response) {
  string uri = request.getURI();
  string method = request.getMethod();

//
// without this scope I can service responses fine; otherwise I get the following from curl and the server aborts
// curl: (52) Empty reply from server
//
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(g_log_mutex);
    poco_information(*log_, "stuff");
  }
  
  if (frag_ == "/" && method == "GET") {
    response.setStatusAndReason(HTTPResponse::HTTP_OK);
    response.sendBuffer(NULL, 0);
  } else { 
    response.setStatusAndReason(HTTPResponse::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    response.sendBuffer(NULL, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was related to me saving the log pointer incorrectly.  Afaict this works & based on the comments of saving the logger once & reusing it this follows that advice.

```
Poco::Logger& log_ = Poco::Util::Application::instance().logger().get("WifiRequestHandler");
```